# How can I print any given target element in a vector?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function that has access to a specific element found in a vector. The goal is that the function would dynamically work with any element it is passed. I am not sure how else to implement this, but I am trying to use pointers and offsets, but I cant figure out how to properly calculate the offset since (afaik) pointer subtraction requires the same object type. Any help would be appreciated!!

This picture shows what I am trying to do on the right side (to get the target element in each item).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qer9Z.jpg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct item
{
    int numItems = 0;
    float price = 0;
    double foo = 0;

    item(int num, float pr, double f)
    {
        numItems = num;
        price = pr;
        foo = f;
    }
};


// GOAL: I can pass any target element of the vector as an argument,
//  and have some sort of loop to print that element found in the entire vector

/// <summary>
/// This function prints any given target element through the entirety of a vector
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vecItemPtr"> Starts as the pointer to the first item found in the vector,
///                           vecItemPtr is iterated after each targetElement is printed </param>
/// <param name="targetElemPtr"> Indicates the position of the element we are trying to 
///                              find in each item</param>
/// <param name="endIndex"> Indicates the number of items in the array that we will have to 
///                         iterate through</param>
template <class T>
void printValues(item* vecItemPtr, T* targetElemPtr, int numItems)
{
    // I think It would be possible to do this by finding the 
    // 'offset' (in bytes) of the targetElement found in each item
    // BUT these items are of different type (*int/*float/*double vs item*)
    ptrdiff_t targetElementOffset = targetElemPtr - vecItemPtr;
    // ^ Error  C2440   '-': cannot convert from 'item *' to 'T*' IterateVectorPtr

    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        // Print the value found at the address of the vecItemPtr PLUS the offset
        printf("%f", *(vecItemPtr + targetElementOffset));
    }
    vecItemPtr++;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<item> test;

    item item1(10, 3.0f, 8);
    item item2(20, 1.0f, 4);

    test.reserve(2);
    test.push_back(item1);
    test.push_back(item2);

    // Say I want to print all numItems in the vector
    printValues(&test[0], &test[0].numItems, test.size());

    // Say I want to print all prices in the vector
    printValues(&test[0], &test[0].price, test.size());

    // Say I want to print all foo's in the vector
    printValues(&test[0], &test[0].foo, test.size());
}
```

Comment: What part of your code works and what part doesn't? "pointer subtraction requires the same object" -- so? What does that mean and what problems does it cause?

Comment: // ^ Error  C2440   '-': cannot convert from 'item *' to 'T*' IterateVectorPtr

Comment: Have you tried overloading `operator<<` for your struct?

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding, Could you explain why operator overloading would get around this problem? I'm trying to achieve a 'dynamic' print function (without hard coding any specific variable to print in the item)

Comment: Can you write what output do you want for `item item1(10, 3.0f, 8);`?

Comment: Sure, the expected output (for just the first) printValues call in main would be (10, 20). If you pass &test[0].numItems as the second argument, it would print all numItems in each item in the vector. If you pass &test[0].price, it would print all prices in each item in the vector (3.0, 1.0)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For your question, it seems that the use of `std::vector` is completely irrelevant, as may be other parts. You're supposed to extract a [mcve], which aims at extracting the core of the problem first.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are trying to perform pointer arithmetic using incompatible pointer types.  Since you need to deal with byte offsets, you need to operate with byte pointers, eg:

```cpp
template <class T>
void printValues(item* vecItemPtr, T* targetElemPtr, int numItems)
{
    ptrdiff_t targetElementOffset = reinterpret_cast<char*>(targetElemPtr) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(vecItemPtr);

    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vecItemPtr + i) + targetElementOffset) << std::endl;
    }
}

...

printValues(&test[0], &test[0].numItems, test.size());
printValues(&test[0], &test[0].price, test.size());
printValues(&test[0], &test[0].foo, test.size());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4oCbzx)

However, a safer and cleaner solution is to use a pointer-to-member instead, then you don't need to deal with byte offsets manually at all, eg:

```cpp
template <class T>
void printValues(item* vecItemPtr, T item::* targetElemPtr, int numItems)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (vecItemPtr[i].*targetElemPtr) << std::endl;
    }
}

...

printValues(test.data(), &item::numItems, test.size());
printValues(test.data(), &item::price, test.size());
printValues(test.data(), &item::foo, test.size());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/gDQMDU)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!!

Comment: I would use `invoke` in the loop, so I don't struggle if I need a `*`. Plus you can use member functions, or even lambdas if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

For more flexibility you can let the function take a functor. Don't use pointers, also don't pass the size seperate from the container. One benefit of using `std::vector` is that you need not do that. If you pass iterators, the same function will also work for other containers with ForwardIterators.

For example you might want to to let the function print the product of `numItems` and `price`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct item {
    int numItems = 0;
    float price = 0;
    double foo = 0;

    item(int num, float pr, double f) : numItems(num), price(pr), foo(f) 
    {
          // prefer the member initialization list over assignment in the constructors body
    }
};

template <class IT,class F>
void printValues(IT begin, IT end, F f) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        std::cout << f(*begin) << "\n";
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<item> test;

    item item1(10, 3.0f, 8);
    item item2(20, 1.0f, 4);

    test.reserve(2);
    test.push_back(item1);
    test.push_back(item2);

    printValues(test.begin(),test.end(),[](auto i){ return i.numItems;});
    printValues(test.begin(),test.end(),[](auto i){ return i.numItems * i.price;});

}
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
20
```